# Powerapps - Change gallery source and patch destination

Tags: gallery, patch, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm about to go mad about an issue in Powerapp.

I'm making an app, which will be used to count inventory in different locations.

I'm using a gallery to show the data from my Excel spreadsheet, and it works fine, if I choose the locations in the gallery settings menu.

However, I would like the text input field in the gallery to show the current value, from the location which I enter in the top text input field. I would also like to have the correct column PATCH when I press the arrow.

Does anybody know how I can make it happen?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the column based on the input box text, set the 'Default' formula of the gallery input boxes to be:

```
If(TextInput.Text = "Loc21", Loc21, TextInput.Text = "Loc22", Loc22, TextInput.Text = "Loc23", Loc23, TextInput.Text = "Loc24", Loc24, TextInput.Text = "Loc25", Loc25, TextInput.Text = "Loc26", Loc26)
```

You can't update tables from a static data source such as Excel. You could however upload your data to a SharePoint site or Common Data Service and then use a [Patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch)  function to update the value in that new data source.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Used the same approach to do the patching in excel :) Thank you so much!